# How to show programs installed with brew in Launchpad?

Tags: homebrew

I've installed many programs with homebrew, but only one is shown in Launchpad. How can I show also others in that menu?

I have to open them from CLI, but someone has difficult name to remember and I want add them in Dock.

Comment: On;y a[ps can go in Dock most Homebrew programs are command line and are run from the terminal. So you question does not make sense at the moment

Comment: I do not believe you can add a CLI program by itself to Launchpad. Even if it could be added it would open in Terminal, execute without any arguments, exit, logout and process completed, leaving the Terminal window inactive and essentially useless. CLI programs need to be executed from the command line or run in a script. Scripts can be appified however this may not be useful depending on exactly what's trying to be accomplished with that given CLI program.

Answer (score 3):

If the installed package has a `.app`, you can add a symlink to it inside your `~/Applications` folder.

Launchpad will pick it up from there.

However, most packages installed by homebrew aren't what OS X calls "Applications", so you might not be able to do it out of the box.

An alternative would be to create an Automator workflow that runs a shell script, and save that workflow as an app.

Comment: The problem with that solution is that homebrew changes the path of an `.app` after each update (e.g., macvim). This means that I have to manually update the symlink after each update, which is tedious. Any solutions?